# questions when using mongoose in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning Node.js using [Beginning Node.js](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484201884) written by Mr. Basarat Syed.

I have come across the following mongoose code snippet.
My question is about the last three lines with `db.close()` and how does the collection `tanks` come up without any statement about tanks.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var tankSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: 'string', size: 'string'});
tankSchema.methods.print = function () {
    console.log('I am', this.name, 'the', this.size)
};

var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', tankSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('connected!');

    var tony = new Tank({
        name: 'tony',
        size: 'small'
    });
    tony.print();

    tony.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        Tank.findOne({name: 'tony'}).exec(function (err, tank) {
            tank.print();

            //======Here are the three lines=======
            db.collection('tanks').drop(function(){db.close();});// The one in the book.
            //db.close();
            //db.collection('t').drop(function(){db.close();});
        });
    });
});
```

My question is what is the difference among the last three lines?
Where did the `collection('tanks')` come from?
Why not just use `db.close()` like the second one?
It seems that I could use any legal string as the argument of collection on for example the third sentence `'t'`. How could this happen?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please frame your questions more appropriately? What exactly is your question.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Sorry for my bad frame about the questions. I have made some edit and not sure if it is clear now. Although X.L.Ant has made the picture much clear now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save an instance of the `Tank` model, mongoose simply infers the collection name to `tanks` (lowercase `Tank` + the `s` suffix), and creates the collection if needed (i.e. if it doesn't already exist), unless you explicitly tell it another name to use, like this:

```
var tankSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: 'string', size: 'string'}, { collection: 'myTanks' });
```

The following statement drops the `tanks` collection you created by saving a tank using the `Tank` model, and then closes the connection

```
db.collection('tanks').drop(function(){db.close();});
```

This statement only closes the connection, without doing anything else

```
db.close();
```

This one drop the collection `t` (which I guess doesn't exist in your case), and then again closes the connection

```
db.collection('t').drop(function(){db.close();});
```

Comment: So the collection `tanks` has already be created by mongoose implicitly according to the Model name - `Tank`. Thank you very much! Much clear now. :)

Comment: Exactly. The collection is created when you try to save the first object, if it doesn't already exists. Edited to clarify this point.